# Make row full of rows vertically scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

For my page I'm using *Foundation*. Great tool, I love it. But there's one thing that I can't achieve yet:

how can I make a row of rows vertically scrollable? An example of what I want to achieve would be *UITableView*(sort of). Here's the example dummy code:

```
<div class="row" id="my-row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      Chrome
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      50%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      Internet Explorer
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      20%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      Firefox
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      15%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      Safari
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      7%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      Others
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      8%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example I only have 5 rows, but in production I might end up with hundreds of rows(for info: I'm not allowed to share the code, so I just posted some dummy example that represents what I have/need).

For this I try to allocate some space on the screen to this row(*my-row*) depending on the screen size with HTML5 *localStorage*. I tried debugging and the variable is being saved and retrieved correctly, then I also use the following jQuery to set the *max-height* for this row:

```
jQuery('div[id="my-row"]').css({'max-height': $theHeight});
```

but when I go to *Inspect Element* in *Chrome*, the *element.style* is empty.

So basically I have 2 questions here:

1. How can I set the height of the row to be max xxx pixels(depending on localStorage)?
2. How can I make this row scrollable if all rows won't fit in the given height?

Comment: @Pete seen that in one of the tutorials. I'm still quite new to html/css/js/jquery and all the web stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#my-row').css({'max-height': $theHeight + 'px'});
```

Or if you want it to scroll too:

```
$('#my-row').css({'max-height': $theHeight + 'px', 'overflow-y': 'auto'});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uvecjt8e/2/)

[Check if the height of the div is bigger](http://jsfiddle.net/uvecjt8e/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y72qf9ng/1/)** showing how it is possible to use `localstorage` to save values and set the height of a div automatically from it. This is one of the persistent ways of saving data locally.

Also you need to add `overflow: auto` to your CSS so that the content actually scrolls.